# In a Trigger, is there a way to find if SObject.addError () had been used?

Tags: apex, trigger

In a trigger you use SObject.addError() to mark a record as not fit for processing. This information can be evaluated outside of the trigger as an exception, but is there a way within the trigger to see this?

Background: we have a slightly complicated processing in the trigger. Currently all issues with a record are merely written to the object with .addError(). It can happen that a record is rejected, but might still trigger updates on other objects. The update routine may not know that the record has already been rejected.

If I am not mistaken, all records delivered to a trigger are processed, even if the first one has an error.

Example:

```
trigger MyTrigger on MyObject__c (after update) {
    for (MyObject__c o : Trigger.New) {
        MyObjectHandler.check (o);
    }

    for (MyObject__c o : Trigger.New) {
        MyObjectHandler.updateOthers (o);
    }
}
```

And the handler:

```
public class MyObjectHandler {
    public static void check (MyObject o) {
        o.addError ('Nope');
    }

    public static void updateOthers (MyObject o) {
        // here, can I find out, if MyObjectHandler.check ()
        // has marked the record as unfit for the database?
        // SObject.getError () does not seem to exist.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no mechanism to see if there are any errors on a record. It also doesn't matter in most cases, because even if "other records" are also updated, almost everything (including governor limits and intervening DML statements) are rolled back to the last checkpoint, and everything is redone excluding the original errors (or an exception is thrown, depending on allOrNone). The main exceptions to this rule are that static variables are not rolled back, and Platform Events will still have already been dispatched. If you absolutely need to know, you would want to arrange a static variable that you can check to see if a record should be excluded from a particular process.

---

### Pseudo-code

```
public static Set<Id> errorRecords = new Set<Id>();
public static void validateRecords(sobject[] records) {
  for(sobject record: records) {
    if(!validate(record)) {
      errorRecords.add(record.Id);
    }
  }
}
public void updateRelatedRecords(sobject[] records) {
  sobject[] updates = new sobject[0];
  for(sobject record: records) {
    if(!errorRecords.contains(record.Id)) {
      updates.add(relatedRecordBuilder(record));
    }
  }
  update updates;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for setting me straight. I had a knot in my head. Tried it, and the transacation roll-back works as it should.